# WebAssembly SIMD without memory

Tags: simd, webassembly

Is it possible to use SIMD without loading it into memory? The only way I can get it to work is by loading it's value into memory and then reading it from memory. Is this really the only way to interact with SIMD values? Can't it read and write from the stack?

This is the only solution I can get to compile, am I missing something or is this the only way?

```
(module
  
  (import "console" "log" (func $log (param i32 i32 i32 i32)))
  (func $main
    
    i32.const 0
    v128.const i32x4 1 2 3 4
    v128.store
    
    i32.const 0
    i32.load
    i32.const 4
    i32.load
    i32.const 8
    i32.load
    i32.const 12
    i32.load
    call $log
  )
  (start $main)
  (memory $memory (export "memory") 1)
)
```

(Solutions in other languages would also be helpful, as long as they don't need memory to read and write SIMD values.)

I'm new to SIMD so any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could load integers with repeated calls to i32x4.replace_lane? As to returning SIMD values, you can call JS functions with the results of i32x4.extract_lane. But I'm not sure of the benefits of this approach; it will certainly be much slower than just passing it through memory.

Comment: @OvinusReal: With SSE2 intrinsics, there are some use-cases for `_mm_cvtsi32_si128` and vice versa, or especially for broadcasting a scalar to a vector.  Similarly in asm, there are use-cases for `movd xmm0, eax` which is more efficient than `mov [rsp+4], eax` / `movd xmm0, [rsp+4]`.  Often at the end of a horizontal sum or other reduction for taking one element of a vector as an int or float, or for vec <= int often for some scalar parameter that's going to affect what you do to every element of an array.  (So usually a broadcast, like AVX-512 `vpbroadcastd xmm0, eax`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes For actual native code, 100%. But it's unclear how JS can interface efficiently with this stuff.

Comment: @OvinusReal pardon my ignorance, why would `extract_lane` be slower? Especially for `i64x2` which required just 2 calls to `extract_lane`

Comment: Hm, well certainly you can pass (a fixed number of) arguments into the SIMD function without touching the main memory buffer, have it do whatever it wants, and then extract 32-bit integers and call a JS function to ultimately return them, say by writing them into a JS array. Unless you're doing some repeated SIMD stuff in there--say, a Mandelbrot calculation--the overhead of extracting and especially returning will be FAR higher, relatively speaking, than going through memory. Note you can't return an i64 because JS has no i64 type, and not an f64 because NaN behavior is impl-defined.

Comment: You can now return i64 as js BigInt thanks to the `JS-BigInt-integration` proposal

Comment: @OvinusReal I think that you should turn you `replace_lane`/`extract_lane` into and answer since it certainly answers the question I asked